# How DateTime.Parse works in case to universal time format

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime

In my code, I am getting Date value as string (reading from xml doc) where no time zone is specified. Here is the sample code...

```
string dateStr = "2012-06-23";
DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.Parse(dateStr).ToUniversalTime();
```

When I check the value of convertedDate, it is "22/06/2012 18:30:00". I want to know how exectly ToUniversalTime() method works in this case and how it concluded dateTime format in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201378/how-does-datetime-touniversaltime-work

Comment: A guess: Parse returs DateTime with unknown zone (neither local nor universal) and `ToUniversalTime` assumes that it is local (when unspecified)

Comment: @firda [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse.aspx) to the two [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime.aspx) pages and you've got yourself an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Parse` method sets the `Kind` property of the date to `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` as there is no time zone information in the string. The `ToUniversalTime` method assumes that the time is local and converts it to UTC.

Ref: [DateTime.Parse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> "Generally, the Parse method returns a DateTime object whose Kind
>   property is DateTimeKind.Unspecified."

Ref: [DateTime.ToUniversalTime Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> "Unspecified: The current DateTime object is assumed to be a local time, and the
>   conversion is performed as if Kind were Local."