# C# with mongodb DateTime Convert

Tags: c#, mongodb, datetime

I want to convert `"ISODate(\"2014-11-13T18:43:33.868Z\")"` to c# datetime ex `2014-11-13 18:43:33`.
 Value `"ISODate(\"2014-11-13T18:43:33.868Z\")"` take from MongoDB collection.

Please Help.

Comment: Have you made any attempt yourself to solve this? What specific problem are you facing?

Comment: Put the c# code in your question

Comment: that's not a C# datetime..looks more like a `TimeStamp` format please show your C# code that you are currently using also do a google search since there are many examples out there and this has already been asked on SO previously.. show more effort please.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556144/how-to-create-a-net-datetime-from-iso-8601-format

Comment: The C# MongoDB driver will do this sort of conversion for you. If you post your code we can see what you might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 5):

You can set `DateTime` in C# to UTC

```
var createDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Utc)
```

or

```
dateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc)
```

Then insert type `DateTime` into mongodb
It worked in my case.

[image: DateTime C#]

[image: Inser mongodb same datetime]

Answer (score 2):

You can store your date as a BsonDateTime object when you pull it from the database, then convert it as follows:

```
DateTime dt = bdt.ToUniversalTime();
```

And you may find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201378/how-does-datetime-touniversaltime-work) useful to learn more about how `ToUniversalTime()` works.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand clearly, just because it writes `ISODate` in your string, that doesn't make it [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The [`"O"` or `"o"` standard format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#Roundtrip) complies ISO 8601 format and which is `"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffffffK"` custom format string for a `DateTime`. That doesn't match with your string format.

If your all strings has a stable format like this, you can use [custom date and time formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) with literal string delimiter like;

```
string s = "ISODate(\"2014-11-13T18:43:33.868Z\")";
string format = "'ISODate(\"'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff'Z\")'";
DateTime date;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    Console.WriteLine (date);
}
```

If you want to string representation of your `DateTime` with `"2014-11-13 18:43:33"` format, you can use [`DateTime.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64(v=vs.110).aspx) method like;

```
date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```