# Different time output for ToUniversalTime

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, utc

I cannot understand or find any information that could explain why there are two different time component output (12p.m and 11 a.m) for the following. Can somebody please explain.

```
        DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2015, 05, 15).ToUniversalTime();
        DateTime d2 = new DateTime(2015, 02, 02).ToUniversalTime();

        Console.WriteLine(d1.ToString()); //OUTPUTS - 1/05/2015 12:00:00 p.m.
        Console.WriteLine(d2.ToString()); //OUTPUTS - 1/02/2015 11:00:00 a.m.
```

Comment: because of daylight savings?

Comment: might be worth reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201378/how-does-datetime-touniversaltime-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ToUniveralTime` method converts from the local time zone where the code is running, to UTC.

Since time zones can *change* their offsets from UTC at different times of the year, the value can easily be different between two different dates - especially since one date is in the winter, and the other is in the summer, due to *daylight saving time*.

See also, [the DST tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info), and "time zone != offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: Thanks Matt. This was the exact reason.