# What happens when we convert UTC Date time ToUniversalTime?

Tags: c#, .net

What happens when we convert UTC Date time ToUniversalTime?

```
DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinute(offsetTimeZone);                        
DateTime todayStart = localDate.Date.ToUniversalTime().AddHours(00).AddMinutes(00);
```

Comment: Can't you debug yourself? Also documentation may help...

Answer (score 0):

There is a -lot- going on when converting using ToUniversalTime. DST is addressed, local time, etc. etc.

Just go to the reference source and read through the code:
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,fddce8be2da82dfc

Answer (score 0):

There is already the same question on stackoverflow.

> here is no implicit timezone attached to a DateTime object. If you run ToUniversalTime() on it, it uses the timezone of the context that the code is running in.
>
> For example, if I create a DateTime from the epoch of 1/1/1970, it gives me the same DateTime object no matter where in the world I am.
>
> If I run ToUniversalTime() on it when I'm running the code in Greenwich, then I get the same time. If I do it while I live in Vancouver, then I get an offset DateTime object of -8 hours.
>
> This is why it's important to store time related information in your database as UTC times when you need to do any kind of date conversion or localization. Consider if your codebase got moved to a server facility in another timezone ;)

You can find the question and the complete answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1201386/3523558).

Answer (score 0):

DateTime objects by default are typed as DateTimeKind.Local. On parsing a date and set it as DateTimeKind.Utc, then ToUniversalTime() performs no conversion. If we run ToUniversalTime(), it uses the timezone of the context that the code is running in.