# Is my code interpreting this date-time string accurately?

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I am receiving the following string from an api:

```
{ "CallTime" : "2018-02-23T16:00:01.806Z" }
```

In my database, I want to store all date/times in zulu time. To accomplish this, I am using `DateTime.Parse` to convert this string into a `DateTime` object. Then, I use the `ToUniversalTime()` to change the time into zulu time (and then I store that in the database).

However, I'm not sure if I am understanding the interpretation of time zones correctly. If I look at the results, this is what confuses me:

```
DateTime.Parse("2018-02-23T16:00:01.806Z") /* = 2/23/2018 10:00:01 AM */
DateTime.Parse("2018-02-23T16:00:01.806Z").ToUniversalTime() /* = 2/23/2018 4:00:01 PM */
```

Isn't the original string already in zulu time? I would think these two values should be the same. There is no indication of a time zone in the original string, so wouldn't the `Parse` function assume zulu time automatically? Or, does `Parse` use the local system timezone and use that to convert the string to an object?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201378/how-does-datetime-touniversaltime-work

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/date-and-time-strings-javascript
That's an ISO 8601 date, the trailing `Z` specifies UTC timezone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does DateTime.ToUniversalTime() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201378/how-does-datetime-touniversaltime-work)

Comment: `var dt = (DateTime)JObject.Parse(yourstring)["CallTime"];` Then see the *dt.Kind*

Comment: Assuming you have the option, _always_ use `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime` (for everything, storage, calculation, display, all of it). MSDN has a detailed blog article from 2012 [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davidrickard/2012/04/06/datetime-and-datetimeoffset-in-net-good-practices-and-common-pitfalls/). Basically `DateTime` is still around mainly because it would break too many things to get rid of it.

Comment: If you care enough about date and time and timezones that you're asking this kind of question you should probably be using [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/) instead of the built-in .NET classes for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is: yes it does.

As Many comments are pointing out, `DateTime.Parse()` uses the DateTimeKind.Local by default-> 2/23/2018 10:00:01 AM
When you call `ToUniversalTime()`, you get the UTC-time again-> 4PM

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. I see what's happening now.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than calling `ToUniversalTime`, consider changing your code to pass [`DateTimeStyles.RoundTripKind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimestyles).  This is specifically designed to evaluate the string and set the kind accordingly.  In other words, when it sees `Z`, it will set the kind to `DateTimeKind.Utc` and give you a UTC-based value.  If it sees an offset, it will adjust for the offset, convert to local time and set `DateTimeKind.Local`.  If it sees neither then it sets `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.

```
DateTime.Parse("2018-02-23T16:00:01.806Z", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                           DateTimeStyles.RoundTripKind);
```

Also, you may find that using `DateTimeOffset` is more intuitive and practical than `DateTime`.  You also don't need to worry about setting the style if you do.