# Date format for +7

Tags: c#

I have this kind of date format:

2022-11-17T15:23:45+07:00

I want to try the following, but I don't know what format should I use in here for +7?

```
 DateTime startDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(sessionDate, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss",
 System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToUniversalTime();
```

How to convert it into UTC+0 with C#?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does DateTime.ToUniversalTime() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201378/how-does-datetime-touniversaltime-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+7` is the offset relative to UTC.

To convert that to UTC+0:

```
var utc = DateTime.Parse("2022-11-17T15:23:45+07:00").ToUniversalTime();
```