# LINQ to SQL Data Context - Date Properties - Change DateTImeKind Unspecified Dates to Local Dates

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, .net-4.0, datacontext

I have a LINQ to SQL Data Context containing a class with two Date properties:

```
DateActive DateTime NOT NULL
DateInactive DateTime NULL
```

The MSDN clearly states:

> The LessThanOrEqual operator determines the relationship between two DateTime values by comparing their number of ticks. Before comparing DateTime objects, make sure that the objects represent times in the same time zone. You can do this by comparing the values of their Kind property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.op_lessthanorequal.aspx

But in my LINQ queries the two above fields are showing as `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` where I am comparing to `Date.Today` which is `DateTimeKind.Local`.

Is there a nice way of specifying the above properties as `DateTimeKind.Local` throughout the entire application so I don't have to convert like `i.DateActive.ToLocalTime.Date` and `i.DateInactive.Value.ToLocalTime.Date` everywhere?

I am using .NET 4 not .NET 4.5 so I'm presuming the same applies.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/823313/1341477

Comment: Why do you want to change the DateTimeKind for the database values?

Comment: Just going by what the MSDN says... what I'm trying to so is be clear in my application that dates coming from the database are local datetimes not UTC datetimes.

Comment: They are neither - they have no timezone. In fact, if you always treat them as local, you don't have to do any conversions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSDN article talks about comparing client-side dates. Linq To SQL converts your statement to SQL, where the DateTimeKind property isn't used.

You should use DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime. This will allow you to [use DateTimeOffset methods in SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716741%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and take advantage of the DATETIMEOFFSET type in SQL Server.

LINQ to SQL generates SQL statements. System.DateTime and SQL Server's DATETIME types have no timezone information so it makes no sense to try and take into account the timezone. None of the two values contain any timezone, so how can you make any automatic conversions?

The two DateTime values in your question come from two different sources. `DateTime.Today` comes from your local machine, where the timezone is known, so it's `DateTimeKind.Local`.

The database columns though come from the database, from a data type that contains no timezone info. `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` is the correct value here. BTW, what timezone do you assume when storing to the database? UTC? Your local timezone? Summer or winter time?

If you want to keep using the DateTime types, you will have to convert your datetime parameters to the proper timezone on the client. Comparisons between database fields do not require any conversions, as the SQL they translate to doesn't depend on the timezone.

If you want to support different timezones, you will have to switch to the DateTimeOffset types.

Of course, you can assume that all data shares the same timezone and ignore any differences, in which case DateTime is enough.

Comment: I don't think I need to use DateTimeOffset, my application is intended for use within GMT / BST only. I'm just going by what the MSDN says regarding the operators for the Date type. And wish to use local times at all times.

Comment: Thanks for bringing some clarity to the Date type and LINQ and SQL DateTime handling, I understand you are saying that it doesn't matter because LINQ converts it to SQL where DateTime is timezone agnostic. However, at some point in my application I do compare them in the application, and not in SQL Server.