# LINQ2SQL: How to modify fields values when loading anonymous entities?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, entities

**!!! Please do not redirect to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823313/linq-to-sql-datetime-values-are-local-kind-unspecified-how-do-i-make-it-utc), as it does not solve the problem described below.**

Let's say we have such table in database:

**SomeTable**

- ID (int)
- DT (datetime)

We have configured a Linq2Sql data context. And we have configured an entity for SomeTable: **OnLoaded** method modifies DT in such way that DateTimeKind of DT becomes Utc (initially it is Unspecified).

Now here is the problem:

If we request data by using whole entity, the OnLoaded method is called:

```
From x In ourDataContext.SomeTable Select x
```

But if we request only part of table (and therefore generate an anonymous type), the OnLoaded is not called:

```
From x In ourDataContext.SomeTable Select x.DT
```

It is clear that OnLoaded is defined in SomeTable entity, and not in anonymous type.

At the moment I consider creating custom entities which would replace anonymous types. But maybe somebody has better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had similar problem as we needed to receive part of fields from entity as anonymous object and always know that we have `DateTimeKind` of date fields as `DateTimeKind.UTC` without using additional functions in LINQ request.

We tried a lot of things, but we found only one good enough solutions - code generation for Linq2Sql with T4.

*P.S.* If you want to learn more about Linq2Sql code generation with T4, you can begin from http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx

Comment: I guess that is the only way for now... :/

Answer (score 3):

Linq2Sql generates partial classes for tables thus making it very easy to extend. Just add `SomeTable.cs` file to your solution (within the same namespace as your auto-generated db context) and define an extra property with any behavior you need:

```
public partial class SomeTable {
    public System.DateTime CustomDT {
        get { return DT.AddYears(120); }
    }
}
```

Now you can query it like usual:

```
        var e = ctx.SomeTable.Select(x => new { x.CustomDT }).First();
        Console.WriteLine(e.CustomDT);
```

**Update**:

Based on the comments I think the problem you're facing is due to incorrect separation of responsibilities. You're trying to pass a business logic (data transformation) responsibility to your DAL. While L2S provides some flexibility here (as shown above) you have another options if the solution is not satisfying:

1. Explicit layer above L2S DAL. Typically it's a repository pattern
   that returns DTOs very similar to ones auto-generated by L2S. In this case you can hide `DT` property forcing consumers to use `CustomDT` only.
2. Put the logic into the database (views, calculated columns, SPs). I
   wouldn't consider this approach for a new project but it may be a
   viable option for some legacy applications.

Comment: This method is described in question itself, but I am looking for better approach.

Comment: I can't see how the question describes using of an extra property which does address the issue you have. It works in both projection (as in the example) and selection scenarios.

Comment: Well, It is simple: we have to introduce custom code, which has two disadvantages:
1. a third-party developer still cannot use DT property directly (therefore whole idea of automated DT property is broken)
2. while using CustomDT in queries, LINQ2SQL skips optimization: it requests all table fields from database instead of requesting only DT field.

Comment: @Dima Linq-to-SQL doesn't get all fields if you use this approach. I think this is the only thing you can do. I tend to agree with these words on separation of concerns. Don't try to use a simple ORM for things it's not designed for. And this is only the select part. What if you also want to update DT?

Comment: It does get all fields, @Gert, I have tested it. Not sure about update behavior, it needs separate testing.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the `DateTimeKind` within the query:

```
from x in ourDataContext.SomeTable 
select DateTime.SpecifyKind(x.DT, DateTimeKind.Utc)
```

---

If you will be doing this often, an extension method might help make it less verbose:

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static DateTime AsUtc(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    }

    public static DateTime? AsUtc(this DateTime? dateTime)
    {
        if(dateTime == null) return null;
        return AsUtc(dateTime.Value);
    }
}
```

Then your query becomes:

```
from x in ourDataContext.SomeTable select x.DT.AsUtc()
```

Comment: This breaks the idea of delegating the functionality to Linq2Sql. If some developer forgets to use AsUtc then he will receive incorrect data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `linq-to-sql` for the query portion and use `linq-to-objects` to grab the `DateTime` property you want (you are not actually returning an anonymous type).

```
(From x In ourDataContext.SomeTable _
 Select x).AsEnumerable() _
          .Select(Function(x) x.DT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code? Instead of using Anonymous type, you can specify the same Table type but load just one field. I don't know whether it will work or not in your case.

```
SomeTable.Select( x => new SomeTable {
    DateField = x.DateField
})
```

Otherwise there is no simple solution to it.